# counting all the rows of appended list python

Tags: python, pandas, list

I'm trying to automate filling in a mysql database with python.
I also need to count the number of rows (in this case should be 48).
But I always get 3 as an awsner no matter if I just use len() or try to use pandas. Is it just an indentation error that I'm not seeing?
The rest of the script does fine.

This is the full code: (removed the connection part to mysql as it's not needed to share)

```
for folder in diff_list:
path = os.path.join(nipt_output, folder)
print(path)
os.chdir(path)
files = os.listdir(path)
print(files)
try:
    pool_path = os.path.join(path, "ProcessLogs")
    os.chdir(pool_path)

    print(os.getcwd())
    for file in os.listdir("."):
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*pool_report*.tab'):
            print(file)
            library = file
    print(library)

    pool = []
    with open(library, 'r') as f:
        next(f)
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
        for pool in reader:
            pool.append(pool)
    print(pool)
    
    list_pool = []
    index_list = [0, 3, 2]
    index = 0
    for i in index_list:
        list_pool.append(pool[index_list[index]])
        index= index + 1
    print(list_pool)

    
    cursor = cnx.cursor()
    
    number_samples = len(list_pool)

    sql = """INSERT INTO pool_report (batch_name, number_samples, pool_type, pool_barcode) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"""
    val = (list_pool[0], number_samples, list_pool[1], list_pool[2])
    cursor.execute(sql, val)
```

And this is the output I get:

[result of the len(list_pool)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCm68.png)

It should be 48, but I get 3.

Comment: `index_list` has 3 elements. You append three elements to `list_pool` in that for loop. Do you want `list_pool.extend` instead?

Comment: When I use list_pool.extend instead of list_pool.append. I get an error about double value

Comment: When doing `for pool in reader:` you are overriding your previous variable `pool = []`. You should change this name.

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like:

```
for folder in diff_list:
    path = os.path.join(nipt_output, folder)
    print(path)
    os.chdir(path)
    files = os.listdir(path)
    print(files)
    try:
        pool_path = os.path.join(path, "ProcessLogs")
        os.chdir(pool_path)

        print(os.getcwd())
        for file in os.listdir("."):
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*pool_report*.tab'):
                print(file)
                library = file
        print(library)

        pool = []
        with open(library, 'r') as f:
            next(f)
            reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
            for pool in reader:
                pool.append(pool)
        print(pool)
        
        list_pool = []
        index_list = [0, 3, 2]
        index = 0
        for i in index_list:
            list_pool.extend(pool[index_list[index]])
            index= index + 1
        print(list_pool)

        
        cursor = cnx.cursor()
        
        number_samples = len(list_pool)

        sql = """INSERT INTO pool_report (batch_name, number_samples, pool_type, pool_barcode) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"""
        val = (list_pool[0], number_samples, list_pool[1], list_pool[2])
        cursor.execute(sql, val)
```